# How to remove 1 of 2 decimal points in a number using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of numbers in Excel ... e.g.

```
1.2345.678
```

I want to remove the second decimal point from all data.

Is this possible via import from csv to dataframe?

Thanks.

Comment: So the answer should be what? `1.2345678`? And it should be float type, not a string?

Comment: I don't think there is this option, or at least to my knowledge you'd have to do this as a post-processing step.

Comment: Yes, the answer should be 1.2345678 and in float form so i can plot the data.

Comment: I tried: y2 = df['Press P'].str.split('.').str[:-3].str.join('.') but gave ValueERROR: could not convert string to float.

Comment: You might want to use regex. AFAIK, there is no option in Pandas for that

Comment: Can't you change the formatting in Excel?

Comment: Is the '.' you want to remove always at third last position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would preserve all digits and just get rid of the final decimal point which is what you wanted:

```
In [80]:
t="""val
1.2345.678"""
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(t))
df

Out[80]:
          val
0  1.2345.678

In [94]:    
(df['val'].str[0:df['val'].str.rfind('.')[0]]+df['val'].str.split('.').str[-1]).astype(np.float64)

Out[94]:
0    1.234568
dtype: float64
```

Note that the above shows a display truncation, the full value is present

So the above slices your string from beginning to the position of the last decimal point, I then split the string and add the last split, you can then convert to a float using `astype`

**EDIT**

A better way I think is for the second part not to split but rather re-use `rfind` for the positioning:

```
In [113]:
df['val'].str[0:df['val'].str.rfind('.')[0]]+df['val'].str[df['val'].str.rfind('.')[0]+1:]

Out[113]:
0    1.2345678
Name: val, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
y2 = df['Press P'].str.split('.').str[:-1].str.join('.')
```

I got the solution.

Thanks for your support.

Joey

Comment: But this drops the last 3 digits, is that what you want

Comment: I just wanted to rid of the second decimal place. I think 4 decimal places will be sufficient. But if you can think of a way that keeps all the digits, please post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like this at all, I would change the data in Excel. But this is assuming you can't do that:

```
'.'.join([a[:a.index('.')], a[a.index('.'):].replace('.', '')])
```

Comment: Sorry this won't work, the data is a pandas Series, not a string, you'd have to change it to `'.'.join([a[:a.str.index('.')], a[a.str.index('.'):].str.replace('.', '')])` I think should work

Comment: Yep, I haven't worked with panda. Besides this will give an error if there is no decimal point, so that needs to be handled as well.